# Android studio jdk and gradle errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It's about the 10 time i try to install and run Android Studio but i have always a problem! I can't work with it! But i want to migrate from Eclipse. I solved a problem that not recognized the sdk path, i solved the problem that not recognized my device and then i have another two propblems!

**1)Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper**

**2)Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\bin\java.exe**

And i can't solve them. The second one it's incredible!!! I don't have the jdk there! I set the jdk path in **Project Structure** and the jdk location is:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Do you have environment variable JAVA_HOME set? It should also point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`

Comment: I don't think it is android studio , it is based on intellij , not eclipse.

Comment: @helleye do you mean from system properties in Windows?

Comment: Yes, from system properties

Answer (score 10):

Solution of first is:

You have to change this line in build.gradle (this is the gradle plugin for Android)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+'
```

The version of Android gradle plugin needs to be compatible with the version of Gradle.

Make sure the distributionUrl is specified as gradle-1.10-all.zip at the Gradle-wrapper properties file within the Android project.

This line in gradle-wrapper.properties (this is the gradle version)

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

[image]

Solution of second is:

1. if you do not have JAVA_HOME Variable into environment variables then

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

Once you have the JDK installation path:

Right-click the My Computer icon on
your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab. Click the
Environment Variables button. Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.

2. If you have JAVA_HOME value then

Change the value of environment variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\ instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\bin\java.exe

JAVA_HOME should be always pointing to the parent directory of JDK or JRE installation inside of which, we find the bin directory containing the java, javac, etc. binaries

Comment: Nice explanation, upvoting from my side.

Comment: I'm going to try your way..hope i solve because i'm so tired of this Android Studio!

Comment: I had updated my answer with more info about distributionUrl into Gradle-wrapper properties file, check once if it done or not. If It would be helpful to you then please accept answer

Comment: My JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\java\jdk_8` still same problem with the wrong path to the jdk by android sdk. Any other solution?